# Why cURL not sending my data to salesforce?

Tags: php, forms, curl, salesforce, drupal-6

I am using drupal form to build a contact us form.

I want to send my contact us data to salesforce.

My contact us form has action  "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8".

I want validate the form details before it is sent to salesforce so I am using hook_validate function which validates the form.

If I directly mention #action in hook_menu then it directly posts data to salesforce but doesn't validates it before sending.

SO, I am trying to use cURL to send data to salesforce.

Here is my form :

```
function contact_us_form($form_state){

     $form['orgid'] = array(
            '#name' => 'orgid',
            '#type' => 'hidden',
            '#value' => 'xxxxxx'
           );

     $form['retURL'] = array(
        '#name' => 'retURL',
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => 'http://www.example.com'
       );

     $form['external'] = array(
        '#name' => 'external',
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => '1'
       );

    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 40,
        '#id' => 'name',
        '#title' => t('First and Last Name'),
        '#prefix' => '<table><tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>',
        '#required' => TRUE
       );

     $form['email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 40,
        '#id' => 'email',
        '#title' => t('Valid Email Address'),
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>',

       );
     $form['phone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#id' => 'phone',
        '#title' => t('Phone Number'),
        '#size' => 40,
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'

    );

    $form['subject'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => 40,
        '#title' => t('Subject'),
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
    );

    $form['desc'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#size' => 40,
        '#title' => t('Description1'),
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
    );

   $form['type'] = array(
        '#name' => 'type',
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => 'Web-to-case'
       );

 //  // Adds a simple submit button that refreshes the form and clears its contents -- this is the default behavior for forms.
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#prefix' => '<br><tr><td style="padding-left:150px;">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>'
  ); 


  return $form;
}
```

Form is redering correctly. following is my validate function :

```
    function contact_us_form_validate($form, $form_state) {
   //logic to check fields.     
}
```

Following is my submit code which is not working :
Ideally the cURL call should not return because I have mentioned retURL in form and retrurn URL will be set by salesforce. Currently I am not redirected to retURL.NO any entry is going to salesforce.

```
function contact_us_form_submit($form, $form_state){

  $temp = $form_state['values'];
  $ch = curl_init();
  foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {

//Set array element for each POST variable (ie. first_name=Arsham)
$kv[] = stripslashes($key)."=".stripslashes($value);

}
  $query_string = join("&", $kv);


//The original form action URL from Step 2 :)
$url = 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';

//Open cURL connection
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);

//close cURL connection
curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at something like Guzzle instead of cURL? It is much more developer friendly... Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks buddy for showing interest to resolve above problem but integration on Guzzle will take a time. I am not getting that what is missing in above code ?

Comment: servlet.WebToLead usually responds with HTML to redirect the users browser to retURL. You might also find adding the `debug` input with the value of 1 useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //returns response as data.
```

I know this sounds stupid, but you have checked to see if you have cURL installed and it is enabled in php right ?

Also you should try checking $result for false.

```
if($result=== false)
{
    echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
    echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
}
```

Just to see if something is up, like you cannot post of salesforce because of some security thing, like you not passing in your salesforce.com username and password or the API key for your account.